# How many reversible gates would DES require?

Tags: des, complexity

How many reversible gates (said counting [Toffoli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate) and [Controlled NOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate), with free NOT) would be required to reversibly implement $(K,P)\mapsto(G,C)$ for the block cipher [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#Description)?

$P$ is the plaintext, $C$ the ciphertext, both 64-bit; $K$ is the 56-bit key; $G$ is any 56-bit "garbage".

---

For any block cipher, the function $(K,P)\mapsto(G,C)$ with $G$ the same width as $K$ can be implemented reversibly (rigorous proof and/or straightening welcome).

For AES, this was studied:

- Kamalika Datta, Vishal Shrivastav, Indranil Sengupta, Hafizur Rahaman's [*Reversible Logic Implementation of AES Algorithm*](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~vishal/papers/dtis_2013.pdf), in [proceedings of DTIS 2013](https://doi.org/10.1109/DTIS.2013.6527794). My reading is that it reports implementing $(K,P)\mapsto(G,C)$ using less than $2^{17}$ Toffoli gates.
- Markus Grassl, Brandon Langenberg, Martin Roetteler, Rainer Steinwandt's [*Applying Grover’s Algorithm to AES: Quantum Resource Estimates*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.04965.pdf#page=9), in [proceedings of PQCrypto 2016](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-29360-8_3), seem just over $2^{20}$ Toffoli gates using a different approach.

---

Towards an answer: an expression of DES's $(K,P)\mapsto(G,C)$ using reversible operations is

- a sequence of 16 rounds, each

  - repeating, for each of 8 S-boxes

    - temporarily XORing 6 keys bits with 6 bits of the 64-bit block
    - for each of 4 other bits of the 64-bit block

      - XORing that bit with some function of the 6 (modified) key bits
    - restore the 6 key bits by XORing with the same 6 bits

The center operation is executed 512 times, and certainly represents most of the gates. There are 1480 C-NOT for the rest (accounting for the fact that the last restore of each key bit can be skipped). The 4 functions of the same 6 bits in the center loop are neither quite independent nor arbitrary. I know several minimization attempts for these, but none using reversible gates.

Comment: Any bijection of $\{0,1\}^{k}$ can be computed using Toffoli gates as long as you have 3 ancilla bits https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/gates.pdf Theorem 23. If you do not have ancilla bits, then every Toffoli gate is an even permutation, and therefore you can only perform even transformations (Proposition 9).

Comment: @35093731895230467514051: many thanks for the reference bringing some rigor to my hand-waving.

Comment: DES as a single f(R,K) round's worth of hardware  with a state machine sequencer and key scheduler can be implemented in approximately 4700 NAND gate equivalents (reducing AND-ORs for S Boxes, using L, R, C, D and a state register).

Comment: @user1430: but NAND is not reversible. Thus the minimizations obtained with NAND are not directly usable (hence the question's last phrase).

Comment: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~vishal/papers/dtis_2013.pdf  This link does not exist