# Does there exist a highly irreversible hash function or a highly irreversible pseudo-random number generator?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, pseudo-random-function

In my [previous question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55646/which-symmetric-encryption-systems-pseudorandom-number-generators-and-hash-fun), I asked about potential symmetric cryptosystems which are designed to be computed by a reversible computer. I am now wondering if there are any cryptographic hash functions which consist mainly of non-injective components. It seems like using too many irreversible components in a cryptographic hash function may destroy the security properties of a hash function since non-injective components may make it much easier to find a collision. Are there any good (fast, secure, not memory hard, preferrably used in practice; I also want to exclude the “provably secure” functions based upon difficult problems) cryptographic hash functions which are built using a large quantity of non-surjective components? Cellular automata based hash functions should fit some of these requirements, though I do not know if anyone is using or seriously considering using CA based hash functions in practice.

Comment: can you point to even one reputable CA based hash function in the crypto literature?

Comment: I asked a similar question before about using the Rule 30 CA as a secure pseudorandom generator, it was pointed out to me that it was not secure .

Comment: kodlu. I do not have any examples of an efficient irreversible CA based hash function that I would trust (since irreversibility throws away the information which is needed for collision resistance and other security properties). Reversible CA's work much better for encryption, hashing, and random number generation. This is why I said that irreversible CAs only satisfy some of the requirements for hash functions.